# PHP (5.5.9) SWIG: how can I pass a pointer to boolean as argument?

Tags: php, c++, pass-by-reference, swig

I am using SWIG (3.0.12) with PHP (5.5.9) to build to the following C++ method (in class arith_uint256):

```
arith_uint256& SetCompact(uint32_t nCompact, bool *pfNegative = NULL, bool *pfOverflow = NULL);
```

SWIG writes this to the wrapper PHP:

```
function SetCompact($nCompact, $pfNegative=null, $pfOverflow=null) {
    $r=arith_uint256_SetCompact($this->_cPtr,$nCompact,$pfNegative,$pfOverflow);
    if (!is_resource($r)) return $r;
    return new arith_uint256($r);
}
```

It compiles fine, and I **can** call the method *without the optional args* `pfNegative` and `pfOverflow`.  However, I can't figure out how to pass by-ref those boolean parameters (passing `null` is ok, but can't figure out how to pass pointer to boolean).

Explicit pass-by-reference is deprecated on the calling side in PHP.  Adding reference symbol "&" to the args in the SWIG-outputted wrapper class also does not help.

PHP emits:

> PHP Fatal error:  No matching function for overloaded 'arith_uint256_SetCompact' in Uint256/Uint256.php on line 113

The SWIG type in question is: "SWIGTYPE_p_bool"

Comment: Why are the optional argument pointers?  Shouldn't they have sensible defaults?

Comment: @HenriMenke those are "out" parameters. They are passed in by reference and can be set within the routine to convey more information than just the function's return value.  There is no way to provide "sensible default values" to a pointer.  Furthermore, I did not write this code nor can I predict all the ways people will want to interact with it, I simply want to interface to it.

Comment: Have you tried including `phppointers.i`? The [docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Php_nn2_5) states this: _"Because PHP has a native concept of reference, it may seem more natural to the PHP developer to use references to pass pointers. To enable this, one needs to include phppointers.i which defines the named typemap REF."_